# Does CLLocationManager Alert comes only in the start of application?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

In my application I want to display `CLLocationManager` alert(**"App name" would you like to use your location**) twice. One at the beginning and one, somewhere in middle of application in one of the controllers.

Is it possible to show this alert twice in application? Also, does this alert come only at the start of application, even though we `CLLocationManager` is set somewhere later in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a system generated alert and only comes when you try to access the location services via CLLocationManager object. And it won't come twice as far as I know, because either user allow it or deny it.

Comment: But if we are accessing location services twice in our application, shouldn't it come twice?

Comment: Once user has denied access to location, user has to enable it by it self

Comment: I think you haven't gone through the docs... Every app needs user consent to access location services and once a consent is given by the user or denied by the user then why it will keep on asking for the consent again and again whenever you use CLLocationManager.

Comment: @Inder : Can you please provide me with the link in documents where it is said so? I need to show this proof when I say this. It will be really helpful.

Comment: @Nitish it is said by me... and this happens try to serach the docs on CLLocationManager

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate :**

You can display an alert that ask user to allow location access by enable location service from Settings.

You can use this on iOS 5.0 and later:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

in your app to open Settings app.

Comment: It CAN come twice if you allocate and then use two instances of a CLLocationManager